# pro-active/initiative-taking as an adjective

Tags: word-choice

How can we describe someone who always takes the initiative?

He is very **_**.

The only word I can come up with is *pro-active* but it sounds/feels a little awkward to me.

Edit:
Dictionary[dot]com has a list of synonyms:

*aggressive, anxious, ardent, banzai, can-do, dedicated, eager, energetic, enthused, enthusiastic, excited, extremely enthusiastic, fanatical, fired up, fired up, intense, keyed up, lively, passionate, proactive, spirited, take-charge, zealous*

But nothing really strikes me...

Comment: "always willing and ready" :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is adjective form of "initiative"?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/71877/what-is-adjective-form-of-initiative)

Comment: It would help to at least explain *why* nothing strikes you; otherwise, we have no idea what you would accept or reject and have no way to craft a suitable answer. This is not a guessing game :).

Comment: One word not yet on your list of rejects is _dynamic_, which suggests having a penchant for taking action rather than remaining passive until directed by someone else.

Comment: Proactive is a commonly used word that seems to fit your sense perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might say they have [gumption](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/gumption).

Answer (score 1):

Just a suggestion: *pro-active* isn't usually how I see people write it, *proactive* (as in your list of words) is more common in my experience. It's possible that your use of a dash is throwing your perception of the word off. 
I would recommend using either of these from your list:

> He is very *eager/enthusiastic*.

As for different options, a *go-getter* is absolutely someone who is *proactive*, *willing and ready* (as Kris said), and *eager*. They are always *on the ball*, another option, or maybe even frequently *one step ahead* of you.

> Jeff is really *on the ball* today. I asked him to print me off some TPS reports and he told me they were already on my desk, along with my morning cup of coffee. A *go-getter* like him will go places in this company.

Answer (score 0):

A suitable synonym besides proactive might be preemptive

Answer (score 0):

I was just trying to answer this question myself when I was led here.  It took me a bit to come up with the best answer I could find: Enterprising.

Comment: The answer would be more clear and useful and more appropriate for how this site works if you had a definition for your answer word and cited the reference. The meaning may be obvious to you, but possibly not to the OP.