# Can we use the word "initiative" as an adjective?

Tags: word-usage, adjectives

I'd like to ask if we can use the word *initiative* as an adjective. I have found it used that way, but there is no entry for *initiative* as an adjective in the Oxford Advanced Learners' Dictionary.

Comment: Where have you found it, then, if it's not in the dictionary? You can use more or less any noun as a _noun adjunct_, which functions much the same as an adjective in certain ways. You cannot use _initiative_ as an actual adjective, though: *“It is very initiative” and *“It seems initiative” are both ungrammatical.

Comment: Thank you very much. I found the adjective form of that word on some online dictionary.

Comment: You should include that as part of the question, then. Different dictionaries include different words, and refer to them in different ways. Noun adjuncts, for example, are often labelled as adjectives in dictionaries, even though they are different in many ways.

Comment: Related :http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/71877/what-is-adjective-form-of-initiative

Comment: What kind of *initiative* do you mean to use? There is more than one meaning to the word. Its adjective form may or may not relate to your context. Please provide the actual sentence with context.

Comment: Depending on context, *initial* might be an adjective you could use, but it won't work for all uses of *initiative*.  One could also use *initiating* in some contexts.

Answer (score 2):

Actually [initiative](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Initiative) as an adjective can be found  in dictionaries as shown below. I'd say that *is not a common adjective* and initiatory,  introductory or initial are valid alternatives.

> 1. Of or relating to initiation.
> 2. Used to initiate; initiatory.
> 3. of or concerning initiation or serving to initiate; initiatory.

Examples:

> initiative - serving to set in motion;
>
> - "the *initiative* phase in the negotiations"; "an initiatory step toward a treaty";
> - Compressed dry guncotton is easily detonated by an *[initiative](http://sentence.yourdictionary.com/initiative)* detonator such as mercuric fulminate.
> - In 1908 an act was passed providing for local option in regard to the sale of intoxicating liquors, by an election to be called an *initiative* petition, signed by at least 35% of the electors of a county.
> - The first attempts to utilize the explosive power of nitroglycerin were made by Nobel in 1863; they were only partially successful until the plan, first applied by General Pictot in 1854, of developing the force of gunpowder in the most rapid manner and to the maximum extent, through *initiative detonation*, was applied by Nobel to nitroglycerin.

Comment: How confident are you that these dictionaries are not conflating attributive nouns/noun adjuncts, and true adjectives? Janus points out (above) the counter-arguments to their claims.

Answer (score 2):

Is "turkey" an adjective? I found it used that way. As in "turkey dinner". No, it's a noun adjunct, in the same way as Janus said in one of the comments.

A noun adjunct is  ([wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noun_adjunct))

> an optional noun that modifies another noun; a noun functioning as an adjective

Is "chicken" and adjective? That's a bit more complicated. There's "chicken dinner" and "chicken soup". In these cases, it's a noun adjunct.

"Chicken" is complicated by being identified with "cowardly" (an adjective), as in "The man is chicken". "Chicken" is accepted as an adjective here. What about "Jack is the chicken man"? I would stick with noun adjunct, even if the meaning can only be determined by context. (Is Jack cowardly or is Jack the man that sells chickens, or is he something else?)

This brings us to your specific question about "initiative". This is commonly identified as a noun and not as an adjective.

Using some examples provided from another answer (there was no context to refer to in the original question), I'll provide some thoughts and then make my point.

> "the *initiative* phase in  in the negotiations"; "an *initiatory* step toward a treaty";

Both cases look like clumsy efforts to say *initial* (in the first cue) and *initiating* or *initial* in the second case.

> ...detonated by an *initiative* detonator ...

A better word choice would be *initiating*

> ...by an election to be called an initiative petition...

This is literally referring the the procedure (noun) that enables a number of voters to propose a law by petition, which is called an *initiative*, which is a noun. This is a case of being a noun adjunct.

> ...developing the force of gunpowder in the most rapid manner and to the maximum extent, through *initiative* detonation, was applied by Nobel to nitroglycerin.

A better choice might be *an initiating*

As these examples show, It's easy to mentally identify a noun that has been used as a noun adjunct as an adjective. But when you to this, you may begin put the word into tortured positions (as adjectives) that make you stare and wonder if they are really right. You'll check a dictionary and ask some experts. You'll get advice that contradicts your common sense. It might be easier, now that you are aware of the existence of noun adjuncts, to say to yourself "there is probably a better way to say this".